# Stuck with undefined Variable, but cant find any typos or other reasons that would cause it?

Tags: python

I don't need the really complicated stuff just yet, I just can't figure why the variable won't define when calculating full order price.

```
#input variables for the pie options

casingType = input("What type of casing would you like, shortcrust, sponge or flaky? Please enter: SH, SP, FL: ")
fillingType = input("What kind of filling would you like? Please enter meat, fruit or jam (M, F, J): ")
quantity = int(input("how many pies would you like? "))

#assign prices to individual pie options

if casingType.lower == "sh":
  casingOrder = .5
elif casingType.lower == "sp":
  casingOrder = .75
elif casingType.lower == "fl":
  casingOrder = .9

if fillingType.lower == "m":
  fillingOrder = 1.5
elif fillingType.lower == "f":
  fillingOrder = 1
elif fillingType.lower == "j":
  fillingOrder = .5

#calculating full order price

orderPrice = ((casingOrder + fillingOrder)* quantity)

#Applying discount based on quantity

if quantity > 3 and quantity < 10:
  orderPrice *= .95
elif quantity >= 10:
  orderPrice *= .88

#returning the final amended price

print(orderPrice) 
input("Press Enter to Exit: ")
```

Comment: ``str.lower`` is the function definition, ``str.lower()`` is the function call (which will return a string). By typing ``if casingType.lower == "sh":`` you are comparing the function definition to a string, which will always be ``False``. Use ``if casingType.lower() == "sh":`` instead. You should also consider to provide an ``else:`` to your ``if..elif`` checks.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.  Your current code hangs waiting for input -- don't expect us to type your test data.  We also expect you to supply the *full* error message.

Comment: Consider those `if/elif` statements. They should all have a final `else` for the case where nothing is matched in the `if`'s. Maybe it should set a default or raise an error. The leading reason for "variable used before assignment" is that the code doesn't consider __all__ of the cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
casingType = input("What type of casing would you like, shortcrust, sponge or flaky? Please enter: SH, SP, FL: ")
fillingType = input("What kind of filling would you like? Please enter meat, fruit or jam (M, F, J): ")
quantity = int(input("how many pies would you like? "))

#assign prices to individual pie options
casingOrder= 0
fillingOrder=0

if casingType.lower() == "sh":
  casingOrder = .5
elif casingType.lower() == "sp":
  casingOrder = .75
elif casingType.lower() == "fl":
  casingOrder = .9

if fillingType.lower() == "m":
  fillingOrder = 1.5
elif fillingType.lower() == "f":
  fillingOrder = 1
elif fillingType.lower() == "j":
  fillingOrder = .5

#calculating full order price

orderPrice = ((casingOrder + fillingOrder)* quantity)

#Applying discount based on quantity

if quantity > 3 and quantity < 10:
  orderPrice *= .95
elif quantity >= 10:
  orderPrice *= .88

#returning the final amended price

print(orderPrice) 
input("Press Enter to Exit: ")
```

Haven't checked if the calculation is right, but this should fix your code.

`.lower()`
`defining the variables`

***Additional information***

To make your code more optimal, it is advised to make conditions on the input values. In other words, if I give anything other than the "preset" wanted values, the program should keep asking me to input a correct value.

Comment: I can't believe it was just the brackets on the lower method was missing, I was too focused on the variable line below them, that's perfect thanks :)

Comment: @RyanJudd `.()` were missing and you didn't define the variables `casingOrder` etc...

Answer (score -1):

try declaring both casingOrder,fillingOrder before the if statement

```
  casingType = input("What type of casing would you like, shortcrust, sponge or flaky? Please enter: SH, SP, FL: ")
fillingType = input("What kind of filling would you like? Please enter meat, fruit or jam (M, F, J): ")
quantity = int(input("how many pies would you like? "))

#assign prices to individual pie options
casingOrder=0
fillingOrder=0
if casingType.lower == "sh":
  casingOrder = .5
elif casingType.lower == "sp":
  casingOrder = .75
elif casingType.lower == "fl":
  casingOrder = .9

if fillingType.lower == "m":
  fillingOrder = 1.5
elif fillingType.lower == "f":
  fillingOrder = 1
elif fillingType.lower == "j":
  fillingOrder = .5

#calculating full order price

orderPrice = ((casingOrder + fillingOrder)* quantity)

#Applying discount based on quantity

if quantity > 3 and quantity < 10:
  orderPrice *= .95
elif quantity >= 10:
  orderPrice *= .88
```